# Django with mongoengine backend and elasticsearch via haystack

Tags: python, django, mongodb, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I use mongoengine as my backend. I try to integrate haystack with elasticsearch engine to index my mongo documents. I follow the documentation http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/ .

When I run

```
./manage.py rebuild_index

Removing all documents 

from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.
/home/t/py/django/boxers/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/utils/loading.py:165: UserWarning: Installed app kombu.transport.django.KombuAppConfig is not an importable Python module and will be ignored
  warnings.warn('Installed app %s is not an importable Python module and will be ignored' % app)
```

My django haystack is 2.3.1